# bash mail: command output in subject

Tags: bash, email

I try send a mail with `mail` command, with the output of other command in the subject

```
subj="hello from $(hostname -s) $(date)" 
echo "data" | mail -s $subj mail@mail
```

but I only get the first part of subject (`hello from`).

why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote your subject, like this:

```
echo "data" | mail -s "$subj" mail@mail
```

If you don't quote it, the `mail` program will not know where your subject ends and will take the first "word" (`hello`) as the subject and everything else as an address.

In general, it is good practice to always quote your variables.

Answer (score 0):

/youScriptOrOutput.sh | mail -s "Subject from host $(hostname -s) $(date)" my@email.com